# Define root folder with 7zip

Tags: 7-zip

I am using 7zip with this command

```
tools/7zip/7z.exe a publish/Site.zip publish/Site/*
```

When I do this, 7zip creates a zip file with a publish folder then a Site folder and then my files.

I'd like that the contents of my Site folder to be the root of my zip file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these commands:

```
cd publish/Site
tools/7zip/7z.exe a Site.zip *
```

It will navigate you to the dir you want to 7zip and then adds all the files in it.

Comment: I can't. I am running 7z from a script in another folder

Comment: @VinTem just put the `cd` command in the script? Shouldn't be a problem!